# How many 4-digit numbers are there such that the first and last digits are the same?

Tags: combinatorics

I got 1000, but I don't trust that I did this correctly. Assume 0 cannot be the first integer, but can be the second and/or third integer. How many integers can be made of the form ABCA, where B and C can be equivelant or can be different? e.g. 1561, 2222, 9079, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$1000$ is *almost* correct.

There is no choice over the fourth digit, if we pick the digits in order, so the question is equivalent to "how many $3$-digit numbers are there?" There are $10$ digits, so there would be $10^3=1000$ possible strings.

However, we cannot choose $0$ as the first digit, so there are only actually $9$ choices for the first digit, and then $10$ for the second and third:

$$ 9\times 10\times 10=900$$

Comment: If the first and last digits are the same, then wouldn't only two of the digits be free? It seems like the question is "How many two-digit numbers are there?" which is 100 including 00, which must then be multiplied by 9 for the number of 1st and 4th place choices, still giving 900 as the answer.

Comment: I don't really understand the way you found your answer but we got the same answer.

Comment: @Isaac Philo there are three degrees of freedom. Either the first or the last digit has to be free, because you have to choose one of them to fix the value of the other.